# LINQ query, using relationships

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem. I want to use a LINQ query against this database:
[image]

A user can have many roles, and each role can have many items. If I had a username, I want to be able to find all the items associated with it. Which means I need to first find what roles that user has and then what items each of those roles has.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Change the title to more constructive and meaningful, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var userItems = myUser.Roles.SelectMany(x=>x.Items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let you have:

```
User user = ...;
Role[] roles = user.Roles;
Role role = roles[x];
Items[] items = role.Items;
```

Then:

```
var allItems = user.SelectMany(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.Items);
```

and if you have a EF navigation property:

```
var allItems = user.Roles.SelectMany(r => r.Items);
```